# Search results, filter by access rights

Tags: php, mysql, search

I have implemented search for my customers master successfully, and it searches the entire customer master.

I have agents logged in who are doing the searching.  Customer accounts are associated with agents.  I need to restrict the search to customers associated to the agent (who is logged in).

How do I do this?

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what your asking here. but is sounds like you are looking for help will your mysql query. what is mostly not clear to me is your having trouble get the data to php in the php or writing the query. it would be most helpful to see alittle bit of each of these things so we can see what your trying to do

Comment: Sorry, but this is about as clear as mud. We need _far_ more detail about your existing system; preferably, stripped-down examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you need to `LEFT JOIN`.   Why don't you `LEFT JOIN` the tables that are in question.  For ex: orders, sales_agents, customers...

Might just work.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to scope your data and your sql statements to the current user.

For instance, let's say you have a table sales and a table users. Functionally, each sale belongs to a user. As such, the sales table should have a foreign key on it such as user_id that identifies, for each sale row, the row in the users table to which that sale belongs.

Then, when you search through sales, you should always add "where user_id = ?" as the first filter of your sql statement, before the other dynamic filters, replacing ? with the id of the current logged in user.

In this manner, all the filter criteria when searching the sales table will first be scoped to the current logged in user. If the filter criteria would otherwise pick up someone else's sales rows, it will no longer do that due to the user_id filter.

If you have sales that pertain to all agents in addition to those that are agent-specific, they would presumably have some marker, either an agent_id of 0 or perhaps NULL, or some other field that identifies them as searchable by all. This can easily be worked into that first WHERE fragment in the SQL statement with appropriate parentheses to keep it together:

```
WHERE (agent_id = ? or agent_id IS NULL) AND other dynamic filter etc
WHERE (agent_id = ? or agent_id = 0) AND other dynamic filter etc
WHERE (agent_id = ? or all_agents_flag = 1) AND other dynamic filter etc
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have uses customers/agents instead of sales/users. In your case, you would need an agent_id field on the customer table, identifying the agent to which that customer belongs. The you would add "where agent_id = ?" as noted above.

Comment: hey thanks. but their are other sales under all users that are not pertaining to this sales agent.  so they have to be searchable too.  I am not sure how to do that one.

Comment: I think there is some clarification needed for a clear answer to be provided. Can you look at the comment above by mcgrailm?